# APP Crash onDetroy LVL

Tags: android, ondestroy, android-lvl

I have a problem with Android LVL,

The app is crashing in `onDestroy` on calling `mChecker.onDestroy()`;

```
private com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker mChecker;
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        InitialReport();

    }
```

how can i fix this?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook/com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook.PilotLogbook_main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3730)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1333)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook.PilotLogbook_main.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5623)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699)
... 11 more
```

thank you!

Comment: Your app crashes, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yes, i will post it in the question within 3 min

Comment: You sure mChecker is not null?

Comment: yes, i am sure of that

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same crash and in my case the `NullPointerException` came from

```
    mHandler.getLooper().quit();
```

because when using the cashed license I didn't create the Handler (but the `Looper` automatically will be quit in `onDestroy()` of the LVL). So, my solution was simple:

```
    if ( mHandler != null ) {
        mHandler.getLooper().quit();
    }
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks! :)